# R function to get many worksheets from excel files and use worksheet names as object names

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have received some excel .xlsx files, each file with many worksheets. I am trying to get all worksheets, each as one R data frame named by the excel worksheet name. The following example with `readText.xlsx` file from `openxlsx` works fine for this purpose:

```
x <- system.file("extdata", "readTest.xlsx", package = "openxlsx")
sheet_names <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(x)
my_fun <- function(i) {
  openxlsx::read.xlsx(x, sheet = i)
}
for (i in seq_along(sheet_names)) {
  assign(sheet_names[i], lapply(sheet_names, my_fun)[[i]])
}
```

I would like to convert this into a function, but just cannot get the results. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
get_sheets <- function(x) {
  sheet_names <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(x)
  my_fun <- function(i) {
    openxlsx::read.xlsx(x, sheet = i)
  }
  for (i in seq_along(sheet_names)) {
    assign(sheet_names[i], lapply(sheet_names, my_fun)[[i]])
  }
}

x <- system.file("extdata", "readTest.xlsx", package = "openxlsx")
get_sheets(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `?assign`

> `assign(x, value, pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), inherits = FALSE, immediate = TRUE)`

> `pos` where to do the assignment. By default, assigns into the current environment. See ‘Details’ for other possibilities.

> `envir` the environment to use.

So when you are using `assign` inside the function `get_sheets`, it is assigning the names into the current environment, the environment of `get_sheets`, and this environment is created when the function starts executing and gets destroyed when the function is done executing along with all the objects created within it. And that's why you are not seeing the created data.frames in your global environment.

So, to solve it, you can use `envir = .GlobalEnv` to make those assignments explicitly into the Global Environment.

```
get_sheets <- function(x) {
  sheet_names <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(x)
  my_fun <- function(i) {
    openxlsx::read.xlsx(x, sheet = i)
  }
  for (i in seq_along(sheet_names)) {
    assign(sheet_names[i], lapply(sheet_names, my_fun)[[i]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
}

x <- system.file("extdata", "readTest.xlsx", package = "openxlsx")
get_sheets(x)
```